# Redirecionar via botão para site - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

É possível redirecionar o usuário após clique em um botão para um site, direto abrindo o navegador ou até um webview. A partir do onPressed.

```
            Container(
             alignment: Alignment.center,
             child: FlatButton(
              onPressed: () => print('Forgot Password Button Pressed'),
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 0.0),
                child: Text(
                  'Precisa de ajuda?',
                  style:TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.6),
                  fontSize: 15,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o [URL Launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher) para abrir o URL's  e outros aplicativos:

```
FlatButton(
   onPressed: openURL
)

void openURL(){
  const url = 'https://pt.stackoverflow.com';
  if (await canLaunch(url)) {
    await launch(url);
  } else {
    /// Não è possível abrir a URL
  }
}
```